# Writing csv file from list but not all elements follow up

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I have to format data from a text book to csv file. In the text book my data are already separated by space so i make a list of string (some contains multiple data separated by space).

When I try to write my list into text file it works well, but when I try to write it into a CSV file, in the middle of a string the writing stops and goes to the next element in my list. Don't know why more that half of my data don't follow up. There is no end line character or whatever.

Here is my simple code

```
# importing libraries
import os

# defining location of parent folder
BASE_DIRECTORY = r'C:\Users\CAVC071777\Documents\1_Projet\Riverstart\Intrant EDPR\6-Background Harmonics Data at POI\test'

output_file = open('output.csv', 'w')
output = []
outputString = ""
file_list = []
i = 0
# scanning through sub folders
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(BASE_DIRECTORY):
    for f in filenames:
        if 'txt' in str(f):
            e = os.path.join(str(dirpath), str(f))
            file_list.append(e)
for f in file_list: 
    txtfile = open(f, 'r')
    i = 0
    for line in txtfile:
        if i == 3:
            outputString = "=Date(""{0}"",""{1}"",""{2}"")+TEMPS(""{3}"",""{4}"",""{5}"")".format(line[46:48],line[40:42],line[43:45],line[58:60],line[61:63],line[64:66])
        if i > 8 and i < 71:
            outputString += line[9:71]
        i = i + 1
    output.append(outputString)
    outputString = ""

for row in output:
    print(row)
    output_file.write(row + "\n")
```

When I open it in my csv file all the data after 0.830% didn't follow up:
[image: screenshot of string printed in terminal]

When I print my list of string containing my data in the terminal it's well formatted and all my data is there:
[image: screenshot of opened csv file]

The text files that i try to read on is like this :

ET H

WHM1 SEL-735                      Date: 09/17/19    Time: 11:46:03.726
HDW                                                 Time Source: ext

Fundamental Frequency =  60.0

Harmonic    IA       IB       IC       IN       VA       VB       VC

2         0.166%   0.137%   0.166%   0.000%   0.000%   0.020%   0.010%

3         ......   ......

And so forth till 60

[image of the text file i try to read on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65YqQ.png)

Comment: Here is the link to my data files https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lcsOtEI4v0dmDMIn7Ta3agAkhURhkC4A

Comment: Pleas verify, you have probably misplaced the description to your image links.

Comment: I prefer to use csv specific python libaray for writing rather than just file write

Comment: Please provide a small sample of your data in the question, rather than providing a download link.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I open it in my csv file more that half didn't follow up"? Open it in what or how?

Comment: How many columns has your csv file?

Comment: the sampe are in the first comment. I try to open it with excel (image linked). My CSV files is separated with space and have around 66 colomns

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

1. You are building a space separated file
2. you are using Excel

Excel is known to have a very poor support for csv files. Long story made short in you read a csv file build from Excel on the same system, it will work smoothly. I you read a csv file specifically build for *your* system, it should work. In any other use case it may or not load correctly...

Here Excel expects the delimiter to be a `;` as it is the default delimiter for a French locale, or `,` if you managed to tell it that. As there are none in the rows, it just tries to put everything in the first cell, and visibly limits the length of a single field.

How to fix:

1. use LibreOffice or OpenOffice. Both are far beyond Excel for almost all features **except csv**. You could declare at load time that the separator is a space and control that the lines are correctly parsed
2. Change the rows in th csv file to use the separator that your version of Excel expects

Comment: thanks for the answer. I don't see any problem if all the my data are in the same cell. After my export to the csv i use the data delimiter function in excel to spread it into multiple cell. What you mean by "and visibly limits the length of a single field" is there any length limits?

Comment: @Vicot34 I avoid as much as I can to load csv files in Excel, but the symptom is clear: for a reason I do not know, Excel limits the length of what it reads...